# VSCode can't select code via mouse?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When click & drag the cursor in vscode, it just won't select?

Thus can't select text in vscode with mouse as wish.

Instead I need to select by keyboard with shift + up|down, which is inconvenient.

Never saw this behavior in any other editr/IDE before.

Any idea to select with mouse on free will ? So that could select then copy|delete as wish.

*(BTW, I am using Ubuntu based Mint as OS, if that matters.)*

Comment: Same issue, windows. Randomly happens and then works and then happens again. Can select text fine in eclipse and chrome and np++ at the same time. Very weird intermittent bug it seems like, but maybe its some kind of configuration error on my part?

Comment: I have it sometimes, even a reload of VSC does not work. I cannot select a piece of text with the mouse sometimes, it's frustrating